# bash error handler does not exit but does print error msg

Tags: bash

I have this failing line in my bash script

```
 cp $a $b || (echo "error in line $LINENO (${FUNCNAME[0]})" && exit -1)
```

and I know it is failing because I get the msg, but the script continues to run.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer setting a `trap` to run a clean-up function which can print the information as you need and perform proper exit from the script. Define your condition for trapping on `ERR` (i.e. on command failure). See [The trap builtin command](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/trap) for other signals you can act on

```
trap cleanup ERR
```

and define a simple function as

```
cleanup() {
    exitcode=$?
    printf 'exit code returned: %s\n' "$exitcode"
    printf 'the command executing at the time of the error was: %s\n' "$BASH_COMMAND"
    printf 'command present on line: %d\n' "${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
    # Some more clean up code can be added here before exiting
    exit $exitcode
}
```

Try running the failing `cp` command again with these actions defined which would exactly point you to the line-number and the command that caused the failure. Its also mandated to define your `trap` definitions inside the function where you suspect a possible failure instead of defining it globally.

There is an option provided by the shell for the `trap` to be inherited by all the functions in the script. See [The `set` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

> `-E`
>
> If set, any `trap` on `ERR` is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The `ERR` trap is normally not inherited in such cases.

Just define the option before your definition of the trap and use any level of nested functions as you like

```
set -E
trap cleanup ERR

cleanup() {
    # clean-up actions
}

foo() {
    # some incorrect commands
}

bar() {
    # more incorrect commands
}

main() {
    foo
    bar
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are exiting from a subshell created by `(...)`, not your current shell. Use `{...}` instead.

```
cp "$a" "$b" || { echo "..."; exit 1; }
```

Note the exit status should be an integer between 0 and 255.

Comment: UV it and that's the actuall answer I was looking for, but I'm much more intersted in @Inian answer, so I gave him the V. Sry